# Probability of forming a 3-senator committee

Tags: probability

```
If the Senate has 47 Republicans and 53 Democrats,
in how many ways can you form a 3-senator committee 
in which neither party holds all 3 seats?
```

The solution says that:

You can choose one Democrat, one Republican, and one more senator from either party. We can make these choices, in that order, in $53\cdot 47\cdot 98$ ways.

But then we've counted each possible committee twice, since any given committee can be arranged in the order Democrat-Republican-Third Person in two different ways (depending on which member of the majority party on the committee is chosen as the Third Person).

---

How are there two different ways to arrange the Democrat-Republican-Third committee based on the third person chosen? I only see one possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the first two are $D$ and $R$, and suppose that the third person is a Democrat, say $D\,'$; you could have chosen the same committee by picking $D\,'$ and $R$ as your Democrat and Republican and then picking $D$ as your third person. A similar argument works when the third person is a Republican.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find

[Number of ways of choosing arbitrary set of senators] -

[number of ways of choosing 3 Democrats] -

[number of ways of choosing 3 Republicans].

Finding each of these 3 quantities is a standard probability task (think combininations, permutations, etc.).

NOTE: I'm ignoring the given solution, since I think it makes the problem look more difficult than it actually is.